# Tkinter Entry Get Error "TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

I'm trying to make a code that takes an entry from a Tkinter GUI and search through APIs blah blah blah.
But when I try to get the information from the "Entry" widget, shows this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/login.py", line 7, in search
    EntryResult = Entry.get()
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import base64
import requests as r
searchup = Tk()
def search():
    EntryResult = Entry.get()
    hypixelData = r.get('https://api.hypixel.net/player?key={MyAPIKey}&name='+EntryResult).json()
    uuid = hypixelData["player"]["uuid"]
    encodedData = r.get('https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/'+uuid).json()
    encodedCode = encodedData["properties"]["0"]["value"]
    decode = base64.decodestring(encodedCode)
    print(decode)
Label(searchup, text= "Search MineFriends").grid(column = 5, row = 0, sticky = W, pady = 2)
Entry(searchup).grid(column = 5, row = 1, sticky = W, pady = 2)
Button(searchup, text= "Search player!", command=search).grid(column = 5, row = 2, sticky = W, pady = 2)
searchup.mainloop()
```

I dont quite know the problem, Im new to Python

Comment: `Entry` should be initialized first. `gen` is an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: I put the Define thing after Entry, the problem still consists... it has something to do with "self" argument being in def search()

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method needs to be called on an *instance* of `Entry`. You're calling it on the *class* `Entry`.

The solution looks like the following code, where an instance of `Entry` is created and saved in a variable named `search_box`. The `get` method of `search_box` is then called to get the input.

```
def search():
    entryResult = search_box.get()
    ...
...
search_box = Entry(searchup)
search_box.grid(column = 5, row = 1, sticky = W, pady = 2)
...
```